# How to set up virtualenv on windows 10 for embedded python

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to embedded python into c++ in win10. I would like to do it in a virtual environment. I am facing 2 problems now while may be the first problem is solved then the second problem will be gone, so I will try to present both of them in this thread.

Here is a short summary of my questions
Q1. python report error saying that there is no encodings module when I am trying to use a virtual environment through c++
Q2. c++ cannot load python module after I add `import pandas as pd` while pandas has been installed into the virtual environment

Here is a full description
My PC has only 1 version of python and that is python 3.8

Initial virtual environment in win 10 by cmd.exe

```
cd C:\Users\A\pythonTest
virtualenv ./venvpy3
```

C:\Users\A\pythontest\testing.py

```
def SayHello()
    print("SayHello")
```

main.cpp

```
Py_SetPythonHome(L"C:\\Users\\A\\pythonTest\\venvpy3");
Py_Initialize();

CPyObject sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
CPyObject path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString("C:\\Users\\A\\pythonTest"));

CPyObject pName = PyUnicode_FromString("testing");
CPyObject pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

if (pModule)
{
    CPyObject pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "SayHello");
    if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR: 001\n");
    }
}
else
{
    printf_s("ERROR: Module not imported\n");
}
```

After all this I then build the exe successfully and run it. Error message provided by python told me that I get no encodings modules in `C:\Users\A\pythonTest\venvpy3\Lib\`. I tried to install this package but no success. I then copy all files except site-packets from `C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Programs\python\...\Lib`. Then I run the exe again, it seems no problems.

I then add `import pandas as pd` to `testing.py`. I also install the module to the virtualenv. I run again the exe and then the error message `ERROR: Module not imported` is printed from main.cpp.

At this moment I really don't know how to solve it. and it seems that it is not a correct way for me to copy all the file from `C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\python...\Lib` to my virtualenv.

As some other threads suggested, I have added and set the environmental variables `PYTHONHOME` or `PYTHONPATH` with no helps.

**Current work around method:**
I found that if I keep using os default python environment and add the additional package from virtual environment, it seems no problems. No sure if this is a correct way to solve the problem.

main.cpp

```
// Py_SetPythonHome(L"C:\\Users\\A\\pythonTest\\venvpy3");
Py_Initialize();

CPyObject sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
CPyObject path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString("C:\\Users\\A\\pythonTest"));
PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString("C:\\Users\\A\\pythonTest\\venvpy3\\Lib\\site-packages"));

CPyObject pName = PyUnicode_FromString("testing");
CPyObject pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

if (pModule)
{
    CPyObject pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "SayHello");
    if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR: 001\n");
    }
}
else
{
    printf_s("ERROR: Module not imported\n");
}
```

Comment: if you are embedding python into c++ on windows you need the embeddable zip file not a venv. if you want to have site-packages (ex: pandas) edit the pth files.

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-382/ under files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

Check what contains your PYTHONPATH. In case it's empty, you need to modify your `venvpy3\Script\activate.bat` and include the site-packages of your virtualenv in your PYTHONPATH

```
set "PYTHONPATH=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Lib\site-packages"
```

Remember to unset it once you stop your virtualenv by modifying `venvpy3\Script\deactivate.bat`

```
set PYTHONPATH=
```

## The explanation

I tried to replicate your problem in my computer (Python 3.8.2, Windows 10).

#### The Setup

First I created the virtual environment venvpy3

```
cd project
virtualenv venvpy3
```

Then I wrote the files:

main.cpp

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "pyhelper.hpp"

int main(){
    Py_Initialize();
    CPyObject sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");
    CPyObject path = PyObject_GetAttrString(sys, "path");
    PyList_Append(path, PyUnicode_FromString("C:\\project"));
    CPyObject pName = PyUnicode_FromString("testing");
    CPyObject pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    
    if (pModule){
        CPyObject pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "SayHello");
        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)){
            PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
        }
        else{
            printf("ERROR: 001\n");
        }
    }
    else{
        printf_s("ERROR: Module not imported\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

testing.py

```
import pandas

def SayHello():
    print("SayHello")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SayHello()
```

(I'm going to skip pyhelper.hpp and Makefile) Compile and run. Yes, the binary runs but the python code won't because I don't have installed pandas in my system `ERROR: Module not imported`. Good. Time to activate virtualenv and install pandas

```
venvpy3\Script\activate.bat
pip install pandas
```

Run and yes, I still have the same problem when my system didn't have installed pandas `ERROR: Module not imported`.

#### The Solution

Ok, time to check what happens with my `PYTHONPATH`

```
echo %PYTHONPATH%
```

It's empty. Time to modify `venvpy3\Script\activate.bat` and include my virtualenv Python package. At the end of the file I include

```
set "PYTHONPATH=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Lib\site-packages"
```

Before entering virtualenv my PYTHONPATH was empty so I need to unset it when I finish my session. Time to edit `venvpy3\Script\deactivate.bat`

```
set PYTHONPATH=
```

Ok, time to test.

```
venvpy3\Script\deactivate.bat
venvpy3\Script\activate.bat
```

Run and success, the program says `SayHello`. Time for the last test.

```
venvpy3\Script\deactivate.bat
```

Run and failure: `ERROR: Module not imported`.

#### But what happens if my PYTHONPATH has some previous info?

Ok, we need to keep the previous information before appending virtualenv Python packages so we can recover the original information when we leave virtualenv.

The code you need to append in `venvpy3\Script\activate.bat` is something like this:

```
if not defined _OLD_PYTHONPATH goto ENDIFPYPATH1
    set "PYTHONPATH=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%"
:ENDIFPYPATH1
if defined _OLD_PYTHONPATH goto ENDIFPYPATH2
    set "_OLD_PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%"
    set "PYTHONPATH=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Lib\site-packages"
:ENDIFPYPATH2
```

And this code in `venvpy3\Script\deactivate.bat`

```
if defined _OLD_PYTHONPATH goto ENDIFPYPATH1
    set PYTHONPATH=
:ENDIFPYPATH1
if not defined _OLD_PYTHONPATH goto ENDIFPYPATH2
    set "PYTHONPATH=%_OLD_PYTHONPATH%"
    set _OLD_PYTHONPATH=
:ENDIFPYPATH2
```

Although, telling you the truth, it needs more testing.

#### Do I have to modify my activate.bat/deactivate.bat every time I create a new environment when working embedding Python?

Sadly, yes. In theory the base script to generate the final scripts must be somewhere but I don't know where, maybe it's inside the binary virtualenv.exe.

Comment: Thank you. It is helpful. Since I needed to add the path every time I create a new virtualenv, I may include that path from c++. Btw, I found that virtualenv in linux is different from windows and may be linux has no problem on this situation.

Comment: Oh-oh, I haven't reinstalled linux yet to test it. But I found that sys.prefix and sys.exec_prefix change with virtualenv if you run the script with python (that's the correct behavior) however when you embed python code in c++ using virtualenv, sys.prefix and sys.exec_prefix doesn't change (keep being the same as running without virtualenv) in windows 10.